# Lightweight Active Directory + Asp.net MVC 5 [Unable to establish secure connection with the server using SSL.]

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, adlds

I am using AD LDS + ASP.NET MVC 5. I am trying to implement asp.net membership. Here is my current code:

**Connection String:**

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://localhost/CN=TCMS,DC=TCMSDATA,DC=local" />
```

**Membership Provider:**

```
<membership defaultProvider="MY_ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MY_ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"     
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"       
         applicationName="TCMS.WebUI"
         enableSearchMethods="true"
         attributeMapEmail="mail"
  />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

**Controller:**

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    return View();
}
```

When application tries to validate user, it returns

> Unable to establish secure connection with the server using SSL.

I tried to search on StackOverflow and other resources for fix but i could not find any solution so far which worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

username and password were missing in membership tag.